Does the two-round system cause greater party polarization?
Is it true that the two-round system produces greater party polarization? My understanding is that in order to win in the second round, major party candidates will have to make concessions to minor parties, which often hold more extreme policy positions. This can pull the major party candidates away from the center and towards more polarized positions.
Does any of that make sense? If that's the case, should it be considered a disadvantage?

As opposed to someone winning with a small percentage of the population but the most votes cast?

@Joe W   Thanks for the reply. Are you referring to a one-round FPTP system? In that case, because there's only one round, voters who don't want to waste their votes will likely be more careful about who they support. This often means settling for moderate major party candidates.

@Joe W  In contrast, the two-round system allows voters to support any party they prefer in the first round, knowing that no candidate is likely to win more than 50% of the vote outright. As a result, many may vote for smaller parties with more extreme policy positions. However, in the second round, major party candidates must appeal to those who voted for these smaller parties, often leading them to make concessions to these more extreme factions to secure victory.
Does any of this make sense?

Doesn’t a typical two round system only has a second round when someone doesn’t get over 50% of the votes and only takes the top two people? Not sure how that forces people to work with minor parties.

In France, major parties aren't in the center. RN is quite right but nevertheless biggest party and candidates from RN couldn't get more extreme by embracing smaller parties.

Second round simply gives people the freedom to vote for whomever they really like in the first round and only vote tactically in the second round, whereas with only one runs voters have to vote tactically right from the beginning without knowing much. Multiple rounds simply mean that more opinions are considered on the final candidates.

FWTW, ACE says among other things "the TRS shares many of the disadvantages of a First Past the Post (FPTP) system, without its countervailing simplicity. Research has shown that the TRS in France produces the most disproportional results of any Western democracy." But that's not necessarily the same thing as more polarization. There is a subtle issue how polarization is defined in a 3+ party system. The def is less trivial than in 2-party case. If you mean that it discards votes and produces more disprop results that seems true. But is probably less polarized across the 3+ parties.

Another point of interest (or dispute) is that in a 3+ party system there's often a difference between the size of the parties (which you yourself mention). And so whether that's taken into account in the def of polarization (or not) also matters. See https://osf.io/mz6rs/download/ p. 7 for instance.

"This can pull the major party candidates away from the center and towards more polarized positions." There is some truth to this phenomenon, but you're probably phrasing it wrong. It's more usually called policy shift or accomodation https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/5C3476FCD26B188C7399ADD920D71770/S2049847022000085a.pdf/does-accommodation-work-mainstream-party-strategies-and-the-success-of-radical-right-parties.pdf

One might wager that in a proportional system centrist parties would be more inclined to do this [in response to shifts in electorate preferences to the extremes] than in a system that more disproportionally excludes smaller parties. TRS is just FPTP in disguise, in many cases (as ACE says).

BTW, this is perhaps not universal, but on some topics voters apparently don't trust centrist parties when they shift their positions. That Cambridge paper says [based on their data] "Accommodating radical right issue positions does
thus not benefit mainstream parties even if they can claim to toughen a stance that they previously
advocated. In contrast, voters defect from these parties to the radical right in remarkable numbers." Their full dataset is available too https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/GBWB8I

Can you give some examples of major party candidates will have to make concessions to minor parties first?  Then, why exactly would you attribute this claimed polarization (remember the French electorate is quite fragmented, which is the opposite of a bipolar system) to specifically those concessions, as opposed to other causes?  For example, as opposed to RN and LFI both holding views which other voters may vehemently disagree with?

The U.S. experience has been the French style multi-round systems favor moderates rather than extremists.

I'll answer as a French voter who is not a professional at anything related to politics.
The dynamics of the voting system
France has a two-round system for its national elections: presidential and legislative (lower chamber of the parliament). In legislative elections, each constituency elects one representative. that can actually make a lot of difference. In a presidential election, the second round is between the two top two candidates from the second round. In a legislative election, the second round includes all willing candidates who had the votes of at least 12.5% of the registered voters (not just participating voters).
Voting tends to gravitate around blocs. Traditionally, apart from strongly left-leaning or strongly right-leaning constituencies, the first round typically selects the top left-wing candidate and the top right-wing candidate. But when there are more than two blocs, there are only two guaranteed positions in the second round! So this strongly drives parties towards electoral agreements before the first round. If your bloc has three candidates scoring 10—20% each while the other two blocs have a single candidate scoring 25%, your bloc will be eliminated in the first round, despite being the largest bloc with about 45% of the voters!
In the second round, candidates will naturally try to appeal to voters whose first-round vote didn't go to any of the candidates selected for the second round. There are two kinds of such voters: voters who abstained in the first round, and voters whose first-round choice was eliminated.
If you look at abstention in presidential elections, you'll notice that sometimes there is more abstention in the first round, and sometimes more in the second round. This is visibly correlated to the nature of the face-off in the second round. 1969 had the liberal right against the Gaullist conservative right, and a very large number of left-wing voters stayed home for the second round. 2017 and 2022 had the liberal right against the extreme right, and some left-wing voters stayed home, though less so than in 1969. In years with a left/right face-off in the second round, except in 1965, more voters showed up for the second round. The number of second-round-only voters is enough to decide a close election. This naturally drives candidates to appeal to the center: you want those undecided voters to choose your bloc.
Second-round candidates will also try to convince voters who preferred a more extreme candidate in the first round to vote for them rather than stay home. But this is less efficient because those votes are, at least, definitely lost to your adversary.
Things do get more complicated when there are more than two major blocs: then the biggest reserve of voters is from the bloc that didn't make it. That tends to amplify the “moderation” effect: you need to find a way to reconcile multiple blocs.
Having said all that, changing gears in the second round doesn't work all that well. French voters know that politicians lie, even if they do often fall for the lies. Suddenly making new promises after the first round is not very convincing.

My understanding is that in order to win in the second round, major party candidates will have to make concessions to minor parties, which often hold more extreme policy positions.

As we've seen above, this is wrong regarding the second round. If anything, the two-round system has the opposite effect, of driving promises (but not necessarily policies!) towards the center.
If there's any effect of the electoral system that drives towards the extremes, it's from electoral alliances made before the first round. A moderate party may form an alliance with more extreme parties in order to ensure that they reach the second round. But does this happen, though? Extreme parties may not want to dilute their extremeness in a moderate alliance, and dominant moderate parties may not make many concessions to their more extreme allies.
Party position shifts during the 5th Republic
I'll take a brief look at political shifts during the Fifth French Republic, i.e. French politics since 1958.
Politics isn't a single axis. The difference between parties is not just a matter of whether they're more or less extreme (i.e. how they deviate from the “middle ground”, and how far they're prepared to sacrifice other topics), but also a combination of opinions on many topics. More or less European integration? Ally with the US, with Russia/China, or none? Algerian independence, autonomy or integration? A planned economy or laissez-faire? Worker rights or free enterprise? More public service or less? Productivist or environmentalist? Christian values or women and LGBT+ rights? Liberal immigration, chosen immigration or none? Etc. I'll look at a few topics and see how major topics evolved.
In 1958, abortion was illegal and birth control was highly restricted. Birth control became legal in 1967 under a conservative government. The liberal and left-wing opposition was in favor, while the conservative majority in parliament was divided, and the conservative government tried to minimize the effects of the law: birth control only became fully accessible after a liberal government took power in 1974. Abortion became legal in 1975 under a liberal government with the support of the left but a divided liberal majority and widespread conservative opposition. Abortion became a constitutional right in 2024 with conservatives and the extreme right divided between for, against and abstaining. Today, no relevant party campaigns against abortion, not even the Catholic extreme right Reconquête. No party advertises an extremist position on abortion. Parties shifted not because of pressure from some more extremist parties, but as part of a general shift of the whole society.
France had a Planning Commission from 1946 to 2006, and a ministry whose title includes economic planning at various times since World War 2. It was a fairly consensual thing (sometimes part of the ministry's official title, sometimes not) for a few decades after the war, when there was a country to rebuild. The last minister for planning was Jean Arthuis up to 1997, a liberal in a liberal-conservative government. When the 1997 elections brought a left-wing government dominated by the social-democratic Parti socialiste with the participation of the parti communiste, they didn't include planning in any minister's official title. Conservatives didn't completely eschew planning to please liberals (conservatives in France at the time were still largely Gaullist, and while Gaullists were virulently anti-communist, they were influenced by the reconstruction era where strong government planning was obviously needed). And on the other side, social-democrats didn't steer towards a planned economy to please communists. Parties shifted because the world had changed, from reconstruction to a post-Cold-War world.
Let's look at trends in nationalizations and privatizations. After the destructions of World War 2, many key sectors were (re)nationalized: energy production, transportation, banks, insurance, radio and television, etc., with broad support from the left as well as the right. By the 1970s, liberals started to campaign for less government participation in the economy, but when liberals took over from Gaullists in 1974, there was little effective change. When an alliance of social-democrats and communists took over in 1981, they nationalized a few companies. In 1986 the newly elected conservative government started privatizations in earnest. Since then, the right privatizes, while the left privatizes less, even when the communists are in government. Here again, alliances with more extreme parties hasn't had much effect, compared to the dominant trend of strong government involvement in the economy after the war, and rising uninvolvement with the end of the Cold War.
Environmentalism is a topic where most parties have shifted positions since it started out as a niche position in the 1970s. In the early days, environmentalists were mostly on the left, but not in the main left-wing and extreme-left parties, which were resolutely productivist. Environmentalism rose on the left as Marxism lost its appeal, but at first, it was not a markedly left-wing position. By the early 1990s, a center-left, primarily environmentalist party Les Verts was the largest environmentalist party and started alliances with the main center-left party Parti socialiste, which was shifting more and more away from productivism. Today, the left is almost entirely environmentalist to some degree; liberals and conservatives less so, but they and even the extreme right pay at least lip service to environmentalism. While it's arguable that environmentalist parties might have influenced larger parties, those parties were hardly extremist, and the shift was mostly part of a general trend whereby concern for the environment entered public consciousness.
I've tried to look at a few different topics. I may well have unconsciously cherry-picked, but I can't think of a major topic where more extreme parties have imposed their position on a more moderate party in order to reach an alliance. Parties have changed their stance not because they needed votes from extremists, but because the Overton window was moving. If you're a French politician who wants to ban abortion, or to withdraw the freedom of the press, or to nationalize big businesses, you don't make that your electoral platform and leverage an alliance with a mainstream party. You pay lip service to the dominant position — and if you reach a position of power, you'll still be constrained by the mainstream party.

+1, amazing answer, you didn't cherrypick. The center of gravity definitely leans towards... the (political) center, not the extremes. If we set aside anti-far right fronts, second round electoral deals are few and far between and when they exist, once in power, the double-ballot majority system to elect members of Parliament + presidential power are an attraction force that drives everyone towards the main block in the government, not the small more extreme party that might have got 1 or 2 ministries.


Is it true that the two-round system produces greater party polarization?

The "greater" implies a comparison, but what are you comparing it to? Also do you measure polarization in terms of the parties difference to a global centrist position, to a center position between party platforms or in the sense of a general vibe of hostility?
Like the first-past-the-post-system (FPTP) favors one of 3 outcomes:

Virtually indistinguishable parties
two opposing extremist parties
parallel movement of political platforms over the spectrum

The rational for the first point is, basically the same reason why competing fast food chains or retailers often put their outlets right next to each other. Because they might get all the voter to the left/right of themselves, but their opponent gets all the voters to the right/left of them. So if they sit in the same place, they end up splitting the market about even and it comes down to nuances.
The second setup is one where you essentially have 2 centers so if your spectrum goes from 0 to 1 you'd have a peak at 0.5-x and a peak at 0.5+x while the center is a valley. So moving towards each other or further apart is disincentivized.
The last one is one where the parties aren't actually sure where the center within their voting population is and so with every election winning or losing they try to realign on the same position and hence you see parallel movement of the parties on the spectrum.
Now despite the two parties being virtually indistinguishable in their politics they might nonetheless pretend that they are totally different and incompatible and polarize the voters to either align with the one or the other while being open to people crossing over. So content wise polarization is less likely while hostility wise that's still possible. Also people have been joking for years that compared to the global political spectrum the U.S. has 2 right wing parties, so it doesn't stop polarization in that regard, but rather incentivizes it.

My understanding is that in order to win in the second round, major party candidates will have to make concessions to minor parties, which often hold more extreme policy positions.

Why the hell should they do that? Like the other party competes them for the center (loads of people) while the extremist parties compete them for the edges (a lot less people) and they don't even have a candidate of their own in the race. So why should they make concessions to those small parties. It's rather the other way around, similar to 1st round FPTP systems it's a choice between the lesser of two evils. So realistically you'd vote for neither party but in if the choice is just between those two you might bite the bullet and vote for the one more aligned with your values to avoid the one even less aligned with your values.
Similar to FPTP systems who are famously ignorant of minority issues, those 2nd rounds don't care about minority parties either.
The thing is just that, unlike what Joe W said in the comments, elections for example in France don't have to be 2 choice run-off elections in the 2nd round. But for example in the last French election a 12.5% result in the first round qualifies to compete in the 2nd round. So you could have loads more candidates in the second round than just 2.
Which in combination with "the plurality winner, wins the election", could mean that someone with idk 30-40% wins the election leading to what apparently ACE calls "the most disproportional results of any Western democracy". Probably because the selected person represents even less than half of their constituents.
Now whether FPTP is truly more proportionate or just better at hiding their disproportional results... again not only do they still regularly ignore 50% of the voters, also a large part that voted for the winner did so not because they liked them but because they liked the other person even less. So realistically they might also score in that margin, it's just less visible, which might even be a downside rather than an upside.
So in a sense the two round system (TRS) might even be more honest because it reveals a more zoomed in version of the political spectrum. So rather than having 2 blobs near the center you have idk 5-6 blobs at different places within the spectrum so you might have a more realistic overview of where the people would actually place themselves and what issues mattered to them.
So if the first round reveals that there is a peak for the fascist right, the center and the left, you might want to field a collective candidate of the democratic bloc that has near 60% support than to risk vote splitting between the center and the left and a fascist narrowly taking the cake. So in that case it might be beneficial to make concession to smaller parties and to somewhat move the platform. While if there is less on the line you could also run a race of 3 competitors and have someone win by a narrow margin. So that the fact that people took the risk and supported their candidate over a big tent solution is also an expression of accepting the result.
Also FPTP has pretty much the very same problem, just one round earlier. In that smaller candidates try to gather support ahead of the election and present themselves as alternatives in order to move the bigger parties to shift their platform in that direction to profit from those voters. Though often enough those struggles happen within the parties rather than with respects to outside parties.
So the outside image might appear to be more uniform, but that's also kind of misleading. So those two systems would be very similar just that the TRS system makes more explicit what the FPTP system seeks to hide from the world.
So as a result the content wise discrepancy between parties can appear to be much larger in a TRS system, but the fact that you have more parties and platforms also might discourage "team politics" where you have a polarization between political groups and a system that more encourages voter migration and issue voting. So as a result it might be actually less polarized in that regard. And if making concessions means that you move your platform to include more people, that might also make it more "centrist" or at least more peaky and less "disproportionate". Now with respect to the discrepancy between that and a global center? Well that's difficult, on the one hand governments might jump around in the spectrum averaging on the center but often being off center, while on the other hand this jumping might not discourage extreme voting as much as sticking towards a center. That being said FPTP doesn't actually discourages that either if analysts would find that populism, scapegoatism and extremism would win them elections.
